# 403 on creating a node via rest api

Tags: nodes, 8

I have an issue with creating a node via rest API. I have the correct permissions setup but it seems like a glitch somewhere in the permissions. An admin can create a content but no other role can.

`{content_type}: Can create new content` permission is checked.

Getting access denied error along with the username in the logs.

Config:

[image]

Client:

```
return api({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'node?_format=hal_json',
    data: JSON.stringify(_node),
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/hal+json',
        'X-CSRF-Token': _xscrf_token,
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Url should be `/entity/node?_format=hal_json`

Comment: What difference does this make in terms of user roles? 'An admin can create a content but no other role can' - that's my issue.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you check the correct permissions for the roles you want in the "RESTful Web Services" section on the /admin/people/permissions page.

Comment: The permissions are right. There is an issue with Drupal. If the role is given "Administer content" permission, the issue resolves. But that shouldn't be the case.